# Why am I not getting the text from my file with this code?

Tags: c#, windows-ce, streamreader, fileinfo, directoryinfo

I am trying to load all my "error log files" into one (hopefully not gigantic) string, and then assign that string to a Multiline textBox:

```
private void PopulateTextBox()
{
    const string errLogDir = "\\ErrorLog";
    Directory.CreateDirectory(errLogDir);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(errLogDir);
    FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles("*.txt");
    foreach (FileInfo fi in files)
    {
        sb.AppendLine(String.Format("*** {0} ***", fi.FullName));
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fi.FullName))
        {
            String line;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.AppendLine(line);
            }
        }
        sb.AppendLine(String.Empty);
    }

    string errLogContents = sb.ToString();
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("errLogContents is {0}", errLogContents));
    textBoxErrLogsContents.Text = sb.ToString();
}
```

There is one file (named "ExceptionLog_2.11.2009.txt"), with some text data, in the \ErrorLog directory directly below the .exe directory (files are created programatically when exceptions occur).

So why am I seeing an empty string in the MessageBox.Show() and nothing is in textBoxErrLogsContents?

### UPDATE

Virtually the same code works in a VS 2013 "Sandbox" app, with just a different directory name, file type, and textBox name:

```
const string errLogDir = @"C:\MiscInWindows7";
Directory.CreateDirectory(errLogDir);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(errLogDir);
FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles("*.xml");
foreach (FileInfo fi in files)
{
    sb.AppendLine(String.Format("*** {0} ***", fi.FullName));
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fi.FullName))
    {
        String line;
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(line);
        }
    }
    sb.AppendLine(String.Empty);
}

string errLogContents = sb.ToString();
MessageBox.Show(String.Format("errLogContents is {0}", errLogContents));
textBox7.Text = sb.ToString();
```

### UPDATE 2

ctacke whammed the spike on the noggin re: my not providing the full path. This works:

```
private void PopulateTextBox()
{
    String logDirPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
    String fullPath = logDirPath + "\\ErrorLog";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    DirectoryInfo di;

    if (!Directory.Exists(fullPath))
    {
        di = Directory.CreateDirectory(fullPath);
    }
    else
    {
        di = new DirectoryInfo(fullPath);
    }

    FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles("*.err");
    foreach (FileInfo fi in files)
    {
        sb.AppendLine(String.Format("*** {0} ***", fi.FullName));
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fi.FullName))
        {
            String line;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.AppendLine(line);
            }
        }
        sb.AppendLine(String.Empty);
    }
    textBoxErrLogsContents.Text = sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Why the downvotes? Did I make an obvious blunder? If so, what? Silent downvotes are not helpful and, what's more, somewhat cowardly.

Comment: Does the target file have any newlines in it?  One case would be where `ReadLine` doesn't return anything because there are no new lines in the target file.  I also dislike the while logic because it's not super readable.  Split that into two, obvious lines where `line = sr.Readline()` and then the `while` condition.  You gain nothing by being clever and everything by being clear.

Comment: also, what's the text format (ASCII or Unicode)? That could make a difference in behavior, too.

Comment: You can replace the whole `StreamReader` and `while` loop with: `sb.AppendLine(File.ReadAllText(fi.FullName))`

Comment: @cstacks: `StreamReader.Readline` will return a line for the last bit of the file, even absent a final newline.

Comment: @ctacke (not "cstacks"):  You wrote, "I also dislike the while logic"; that was an "improvement" (elegantizatory modification/refactoring) that I allowed Resharper to make.

Comment: in another comment you say the file is at "Computer\WindowsCE\Program Files\HHS\ErrorLog".  On the device that would be `\Program Files\HHS\ErrorLog` *not* just `\ErrorLog`.  There's probably the root of the issue.  Remember, there are no relative paths on devices.

Comment: @ctacke: That was it; see Update 2; make this an answer, and I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, calling `CreateDirectory` in all cases is a bad idea.  It's confusing.  Instead, check to see if the directory exists, and if it doesn't then create it and exit the function (because if you created it, you know there's no data).  This would have found your error much faster and also prevented @Jim Mischel's (and everyone else's) confusion.

The problem with your code is actually rooted in one of your comments. You say the file, as seen from your PC with WMDC, is at `Computer\WindowsCE\Program Files\HHS\ErrorLog`. On the device itself that equates to `\Program Files\HHS\ErrorLog` **not** just `\ErrorLog`. Remember, there are no relative paths on Windows CE devices.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't make any sense:

```
const string errLogDir = "\\ErrorLog";
Directory.CreateDirectory(errLogDir);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(errLogDir);
FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles("*.txt");
```

So you're *creating a new directory*, and then trying to read files from it. In this case, you're creating the directory at the root (i.e. "C:\ErrorLog", if the drive of the current working directory is C:).

If the directory you asked to create already exists, `CreateDirectory` just returns the `DirectoryInfo` object. But if you create a new directory and then try to get files from it, it's pretty likely that there will be no files at all because you just created an empty directory.

It's likely that you wanted that to be

```
const string errorLogDir = "ErrorLog";
```

That will cause the directory to be created as a subdirectory of the current working directory.

By the way, there's no readon to have:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(errLogDir);
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(errLogDir);
```

`CreateDirectory` *returns a `DirectoryInfo` object*. So you can write:

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(errLogDir);
```

Now, it's quite possible that the EXE directory is not the same as the current working directory. If you want to get the information from the EXE's subdirectory, then you have to explicitly say so:

```
string fullName = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;
string exeDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(fullName);
string fullErrLogDir = Path.Combine(exeDirectory, errLogDir);
DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(fullErrLogDir);
```

Finally, you can replace all of this code:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fi.FullName))
{
    String line;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        sb.AppendLine(line);
    }
}
```

With a single line:

```
sb.AppendLine(File.ReadAllText(fi.FullName));
```

Comment: Oops, I was adding comments to the other answer instead of here. But as to getting rid of the "CreateDirectory" call, before it was there (I had forgot to create it programmatically in that way), I got: "System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: DirectoryNotFoundException"
In fact, that is one of the two exception msgs that are in the file I'm trying to open from within the app.

Comment: GetEntryAssembly is not available in CE, apparently. The same thing goes for ReadAllText()

Comment: If you're getting a "directory not found" then there's definitely an issue.  You should do a `if !Directory.Exists(..)` and if it's not there then create it and exit.